# undefined reference when using extern

Tags: c++, extern, undefined-reference

I have the following setup (hopefully this is not too bare an example):

**A.h**

```
typedef std::map<unsigned int, float> MyClass;
extern MyClass inst;
```

**A.cpp**

```
MyClass inst;
```

**B.h**

```
#include <A.h>
void foo();
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include <B.h>
void foo {
    inst.myClassFunc();
}
```

Now, when I use inst in `B.cpp` I get `undefined reference to inst`.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you #include the definition of `class MyClass` in B.cpp?

Comment: You should include the full compiler error message in your post.

Answer (score 18):

I know this question is old, but it still might be helpful for someone.

The global variable (here: `MyClass inst`) *should not be* `extern` *for the compilation unit which define* it (here: `A.cpp`)

One way to achieve this:

- **declare** your global variable in a **separate header** (let's say `global.h`) and include this header in the *cpp using these.
- remove the `extern` keyword for the compilation unit which **define** them (e.g. with `#ifdef`) :

global.h looks like:

```
#ifdef A_H_
  #define EXTERN
#else
  #define EXTERN extern
#endif

EXTERN MyClass inst;
```

while A.h looks like:

```
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

// your header content (without globals)

#endif /* A_H_ */
```

and A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "global.h" // after A.h inclusion, we need A_H_ definition
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is too bare an example to work out what's going on.  However, based on the above it's entirely possible that when it hits the failing line the compiler has no knowledge of what's actually in `MyClass` and therefore cannot resolve `MyClassFunc`.

We would need to see the definition of MyClass and know where it is to answer for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the above mentioned file A.cpp as

```
g++ -c A.cpp
g++ -c B.cpp
```

and then while creating the executable you should write the command as follows:

```
g++ A.o B.o
```

Comment: Or in one step, `g++ A.cpp B.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

From the basic example code you posted I'd say you've forgotten to `#include <B.h>` in your B.cpp file.